# Awk - filter only dates with certain format from text file

Tags: bash, macos, awk

I have a .txt file with many lines of text on macOS. I would like to filter only dates and have them saved in order of appearance line by line in a new text file.

I am, however, not interested in all dates, only in those who are complete, looking like 02/03/2019, and those where the number of days is below 13, i. e. 01...12.

Then, I would like to have those dates removed where the number for the day and month are the same like 01/01/2019 and 02/02/2019 etc.

How can I achieve this with `awk` or similar software in bash?

Comment: Please post more clear sample of input and expected output in your post and let us know then.

Comment: Format dd/mm/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy ?

Comment: dd/mm/yyyy, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Deleting Dates Inside a Text File

The following command will delete all dates of the form<sup>✱</sup> `aa/bb/cccc` where `aa` = `bb` < 13. The original file will be copied to `yourFile.txt.bak` as a backup and the new text with deleted dates will overwrite the old file.

```
sed -E -i.bak 's:\b(0[0-9]|1[0-2])/\1/[0-9]{4}\b::g' yourFile.txt
```

If you want to insert something instead of just deleting the dates you can do so by writing the replacement between the two `::`. For instance `sed … 's:…:deleted date:/g' …` will replace each matching date with the text `deleted date`.

<sub>✱ Note that it doesn't matter for your criterion whether the date format is `dd/mm/yyyy` or `mm/dd/yyyy` since your are only interested in dates where `dd` and `mm` are equal.</sub>

#### Extracting Specific Dates From A Text File

If you do not want to delete, but only extract specific dates as mentioned in your comment, you can use the following command.

```
grep -Eo '\b([0-9]{2}/){2}[0-9]{4}\b' yourFile.txt | awk -F/ '$1<13 && $1!=$2'
```

This will extract all dates in **`dd/mm/yyyy` (!)** format where `mm` ≠ `dd` < 13. The dates are printed in order of appearance on stdin. If you want to save them to a file append `> yourOutputFile.txt` to the end of the command.

Comment: Thank you, Socowi, for answering. I am interested in complete dates with day numbers below 13 and without dates equal numbered for days and months, in fact. I want, hence, dates like 01/01/2019 and 12/12/2019 removed from the file. The file which contains text shall be afterwards a list of dates in order of appearance with the above criterion where each line only contains one date. Is this what your code does? I cannot check it out right now as I am away from my MacBook.

Comment: @TilHund That's not how I understood your question. Good that you made it more clear. You should add the clarification to your question. I added another command to my answer which does what you asked for in your comment.

Comment: Thank you, Socowi, for your modification. Your updated command seems to function, however, it does extract dates like 28/02/1978 (format is always `dd/mm/yyyy`). Your command does not seem to correctly remove those (complete) dates where `dd >= 13`. :/ Can you please fix this?

Comment: @TilHund As pointed out in the text under the command, I assumed the format `mm/dd` not `dd/mm`. I edit the answer.

Comment: Thank you, Socowi. I saw that you assumed another format. Sorry, I should have been clearer in my initial post, but you got it right anyways. ;) It works now like charm!

Answer (score 2):

If perl is a choice:

`perl -ne 'print if m:(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(\d\d\d\d): && $1 < 13 && $1 != $2' dates.txt >newdates.txt`

this assumes this format `/dd/mm/yyyy`

Note that I am using a `m: :` notation instead of the usual `/ /` for regex matching. Thus I do not need to escape the `/` slashes in the date.